# Jobberbase installation - Free PHP job board

Tags: php, web, phpmyadmin

I would like to install Jobberbase in my website. I have a hosting plan with JustHost.

Any easy step by step guide to install this job board would be greatly appreciated?

Many Thanks!

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on ServerFault.

Comment: Sorry! will not do this again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some fairly detailed set up documentation [on the jobberBase Wiki](http://wiki.jobberbase.com/) - so this would most likely be a sensible first port of call.

That said, as @Mike Dimmick says this isn't really a StackOverflow question as it's not programming related.